# How do I find a row where specific text appears? Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, formulas

I am using IMPORTDATA to get information from a page. I need to know the specific row that a text appears. This text is unique in the metadata, but it did not appear alone in the cell.

It usually appears like this.

```
<div class="apphub_AppName">SOME RANDOM TEXT FOR EACH PAGE</div>
```

The apphub_AppName is unique in the data, But I can not find the row just with that. With the full name that appears in the row I can find using the MATCH.

```
A01 = <div class="apphub_AppName">SOME RANDOM TEXT FOR EACH PAGE</div>

=match(A1;A2:A2000;0)
```

But I do not know what the random name will be. The easiest way would be to know in which row the word "apphub_AppName" appears.

I'm trying to use MATCH, LOOKUP, VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP. But none is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula to find the row number in which "apphub_AppName" appears.  The formula assumes the random output is in column A

```
=FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(FIND("apphub_AppName",A2:A)>0,ROW(A2:A))),ARRAYFORMULA(IF(FIND("apphub_AppName",A2:A)>0,ROW(A2:A)))>0)
```